# Handling invalid and empty arguments while using optional argparse arguments

Tags: python, conditional-statements, argparse

Below is an example code that uses `argparse`

```
import os
import numpy
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
    parser.add_argument('-C','--Chk',type=str, help='Choose arg')
    parser.add_argument('-R','--ReC',type=str, help='Choose arg')
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
 
    if args['Chk'] == 'compo1':
        print('This is comp1')
    elif args['Chk'] == 'compo2':
        print('This is comp2')
    else:
        print('The specified comp does not exist')
    
    if args['ReC'] == 'recompo':
        print('This is second test')
    else:
        print('The specified second_T does not exist')

     
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The above code works fine. Since both are `optional arguments`, I would like to have two features:

1. If invalid arguments are given, for `-C` or `-R` I would like to print/raise a message. I tried using `raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError`,  see below.

```
if len(args) > 8 or len(args) < 3:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError('Print this error message')
        return
```

2. Secondly, I would like to have situations where the code should not do anything if either of `-C` or `-R` are not given. In the above code, if no arguments are given in either case, it prints `The specified comp does not exist` which is not ideal.

Any better way to do the above tasks ? Thanks

Comment: `args` is a `dict` with 2 items.  What's with the `len` test?

Comment: @hpaulj if the string is given wrong during execution, I would like to print a message. So, thought of using the `len(str)` length as a criterion. It should be `len(args['Chk'])`

Comment: If there's a small set of allowed strings you could use the `choices`.  The `type` function can also be used to test for allowable values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `choices`, `argparse` will test for a specific set of values:

```
In [44]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ...: parser.add_argument('-C','--Chk',choices=['compo1','compo2'], help='Choose arg', default='foobar')
    ...: parser.add_argument('-R','--ReC',choices=['recompo'], help='Choose arg', default='xxx');
```

Acceptable:

```
In [45]: parser.parse_args('-C compo1 -R recompo'.split())
Out[45]: Namespace(Chk='compo1', ReC='recompo')
```

Defaults - I specified some strings; default default is None:

```
In [46]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[46]: Namespace(Chk='foobar', ReC='xxx')
```

A wrong choice raises an error with usage and exit:

```
In [47]: parser.parse_args('-C compo1 -R recomp1'.split())
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-C {compo1,compo2}] [-R {recompo}]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: argument -R/--ReC: invalid choice: 'recomp1' (choose from 'recompo')
```

A `type` function could be used instead if you want to limit the string lengths instead.

Otherwise, post-parsing testing of values is best, even if the logic looks a bit messy.

Comment: @hauji Thank you.But, I dont want both -R and -C to be excecuted from command line. Either -R or -C should suffice. e.g., `python main.py -R recompo` should work even without -C

Comment: write your tests to ignore the variable if it has the default value (easiest if using the `None` default.)

Answer (score 0):

for error handling, you can check this way:

```
class ArgumentParserError(Exception): pass
class ThrowingArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def error(self, message):
        raise ArgumentParserError(message)
```

and this is maybe some help for you:

```
parser = ThrowingArgumentParser(description="YOUR DESCRIPTION")
parser.add_argument('func', nargs='?', choices=['C','R'], const='')
```

Comment: Why do you suggest to use a positional argument ? is it due to having atleast one optional argument during execution ?